# deploying pre funded OZ account with starknet js

Tags: javascript, starknet

a few specs : running on goerli alpha, starknet js 0.4.9

I am trying to deploy a prefunded 0.5.0 openzeppelin account.

I found the class hash to be : `ACC_CLASS_HASH=0x750cd490a7cd1572411169eaa8be292325990d33c5d4733655fe6b926985062`

I have then pre-calculated the address, using this function

```
export function calcAddress(mnemonic?: string): string {
  const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
  let currentMnemonic = mnemonic ? mnemonic : wallet.mnemonic.phrase;
  
  console.log(`calculating address for seed : ${currentMnemonic}`);
  const starkKeyPair = getStarkPair(currentMnemonic, 0);
  let starkKeyPub = ec.getStarkKey(starkKeyPair);
  return hash.calculateContractAddressFromHash(starkKeyPub, ACC_CLASS_HASH, [starkKeyPub], 0);
}
```

and then I deploy it with

```
export async function deployAcc(mnemonic: string, address: string) {
  console.log(`generating keypair from mnemonic`);
  const starkKeyPair = getStarkPair(mnemonic, 0);
  console.log(`generation succesful`);
  const starkKeyPub = ec.getStarkKey(starkKeyPair);
  let futureAcc = new Account(provider, address, starkKeyPair);
  const accountResponse = await futureAcc?.deployAccount({
    classHash: ACC_CLASS_HASH,
    constructorCalldata: [starkKeyPub],
    addressSalt: starkKeyPub,
    contractAddress: address
  });
  console.log(`tx hash : ${accountResponse?.transaction_hash}`);
  await provider.waitForTransaction(accountResponse?.transaction_hash);
}
```

when I try to deploy the account I'd keep getting

```
Entry point 0x36fcbf06cd96843058359e1a75928beacfac10727dab22a3972f0af8aa92895 not found in contract with class hash 0x750cd490a7cd1572411169eaa8be292325990d33c5d4733655fe6b926985062.
```

further googling for entry point 0x36fcbf06cd96843058359e1a75928beacfac10727dab22a3972f0af8aa92895 led me to assume that the entry point is for validate invocation?

as indicated here https://starknet.io/docs/hello_starknet/cli.html

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking about this code:
https://github.com/amanusk/starknet-cli-wallet/blob/develop/scripts/deploy-prefunded.ts

As you correctly stated, the missing entry point which is missing from the contract is `__validate_deploy__`.
(You can calculate it:)

```
from starkware.starknet.public.abi import (get_selector_from_name)

print(hex(get_selector_from_name("__validate_deploy__")))
```

The entry point was introduced in version `0.10.1`, and its purpose is to check the validity of an account deployment when a new account is first initialized.

The current version of the repo above is using OZ contracts version `0.5.0`. This version does not yet implement the entry point `__validate_deploy__`, and you are thus getting this error when trying to deploy a pre-funded account.

This should be supported in the next version currently in PR:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/cairo-contracts/pull/503

The contracts in the repo will be updated once the official release is published.

You can get a sneak peek in this branch:
https://github.com/amanusk/starknet-cli-wallet/tree/validate-deploy

Comment: Hey bleaknight here from telegram, yep, this is it. 

Found your repo after posting the question :)

looking forward to the updates and contributing!